# Live Authentication and Permission Scopes

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-mobile-services, microsoft-live-connect

I'm looking to only ask for a very specific set of permissions in my App Services Mobile App.
I'm using Microsoft Account authentication and I looked at the multiple scopes but none offer me what I need.

wl.basic asks for too much, contacts, etc. How Can I ask for just access to email address and sign-in?

Wunderlist is a perfect example of what I'm looking for, image attached below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog post which describes the feature I think you're asking for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2013/11/25/what-s-new-in-azure-mobile-services-1-6-4247.aspx

> You can now set custom scopes required in the web-based login by using special app settings in the "configure" tab of your mobile service. The scopes are specified as space-separated values in the keys "MS_FacebookScope", "MS_GoogleScope" and "**MS_MicrosoftScope**" for Facebook, Google and Microsoft accounts respectively.

Documentation on which scopes are available can be found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631845.aspx

My guess is the two scopes you need are [wl.signin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631845.aspx#wlsignin) and [wl.emails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631845.aspx#wlemails).  If you were to go with these two, then you just add the MS_MicrosoftScope and set it to "wl.signin wl.emails".  You should be able to separate individual scopes using a space or a comma.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you're able to use extended scopes without using basic. Those 2 scopes were exactly what I needed.

Comment: @MattF Great, glad that was helpful! Would you mind marking this as the answer? :)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, couldn't find where to mark as an answer!
Thanks again :D